# Is $x\sin x$ Surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry

I have to determine whether $x\sin x$ 
Is a surjective function, in $\Bbb R$.

**My solution:**

Let $f(x)=x\sin x$.

$f(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$f(-\frac{\pi}{2})=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Therefore in the closed interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $f(a)\cdot f(b)$<$0$, where $a=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $b=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

From the IVT therorem, there is a root to $f(x)$ in that interval.

Since $\sin$ is a Periodic function, I can always find a closed interval which satisfies IVT.

Therefore, $f(x)$ is surjective.

I don't know how to formalize the solution and whether or not I'm right.

Comment: What is the domain of your function?

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry, added the domain R

Comment: OK. I assume the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ as well?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes.

Comment: I can say as well that 0=t and that f(a) <t<f(b).

Comment: Are you sure you are proving the right thing? You seem to concentrate on finding $x$ with $x\sin x=0$, but that is of course simply $x=0$. How would you proceed to show that there exists $x\in \Bbb R$ with $x\sin x=10^{100}$? - (But the idea of using IVT is of course correct)

Comment: Maybe I can calculate one side limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)=+\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty }f\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}-2n\pi\right)=-\infty.$$

Therefore, by intermediate value theorem, it's surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Take $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, there exists a unique $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$y\in [2\pi k +\frac{\pi}{2}, 2\pi(k+1)+\frac{\pi}{2}) = [y_1, y_2).$$

Now, $f(2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $f(2\pi(k+1))+\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2\pi(k+1))+\frac{\pi}{2}$. Use the IVT on $[y_1, y_2]$ to show that $y$ is the image by the (continuous) $f$ of some $x\in [y_1, y_2]$.